# State the domain of analyticity of $f(z)= e^{e^{z}}$. Differentiate it. Find CREs.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find  the real and imaginary parts of function and apply Cauchy-Rieman Eqautions.
Using chain rule, I put $u= e^{z}$,
so $ f(z)=e^u $
  $ df/dz=d(e^u/du) .(d e^z/dz)= e^u. e^z$
$= e^{e^{z}}.e^x$
$=e^{{e^{z}} + z} $
$ = e^{e^{x+iy} + x+iy}$

I know that domain of analyticity does not include those points where function is not differentiable  so infinity is excluded but I am not sure how to separate the 
real and complex parts of this function to apply CREs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = x + iy$. Then, 
$$e^z = e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{e^z}=e^{e^x(\cos(y) + i\sin(y))} = e^{e^x\cos(y)}e^{i(e^x\sin(y))} = e^{e^x\cos(y)}(\cos(e^x\sin(y) + i\sin(e^x\sin(y))$$
And that takes care of separating $f$ into its real and complex parts. I'll leave it up to you to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations since it's just a simple (though tedious) exercise in partial differentiation.

As for analyticity, we know that $e^z$ is an entire function (i.e. it's analytic everywhere). Since the composition of analytic functions is also analytic, the composition of $e^z$ with itself, which is $f(z) = e^{e^z}$, is analytic everywhere in the complex plane.